# JMETER firing multiple soap request stored in one file

Tags: soap, jmeter

I make a jmeter project that allows to test performance for a web service. I extract from my bdd the soap request and i store all the data in a file (xml). I created the project jmeter and specify the file. I noticed that the project jmeter send all the data and the web service execute just one soap request. So, i want to know if it is possible and how to specify to jmeter to send one by one the data from the file.

**EDIT**

Exemple in the file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="" xmlns:typ="">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<typ:annonce>
    data
</typ:annonce>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="" xmlns:typ="">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<typ:annonce>
    data
</typ:annonce>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, in my file i have two soap requests. JMETER sends the entire file, so my web service execute only the first soap request.
I want that JMETER sends the first soap and after the second.
It is possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function like:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.xml,,)}
```

Directly in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body like:

[image: JMeter FileToString example]

The function will be evaluated when the sampler will be executed so JMeter will pick up the file and send it as the request body.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Thanks to your response. I tested your solution but it is not working for me. I edit my question where i explain in details what i want.